# How to set default file permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, permissions, database

I have ran these codes:

```
sudo chown -R /
sudo chmod 755 /
```

And now my server is not working. I need to get backup copy of MySQL database
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That was a big failure to do so. There is a tool for macos to restore permissions for the filesystem, but as long as you don't have a backup of your server you are lost.